# CSS to remove the hyperlink below the avatar image

Tags: hyperlink

I would like help on a css code to remove the hyperlink found under the avatar image on the discussion forum gadget. For privacy reasons, users are not allowed to see the profile information of others.  The hyperlink should just be a regular text. Unfortunately I am an amateur learning to build a small community website and have no knowledge on css language.

Comment: show us your code

Comment: Well I don’t have one because I don’t really know how to create one. What I have is webpage name pageId=18050

Comment: CSS can't remove anything, only hide it. If the privacy is your concern, you have to get rid of it

Comment: Oop it’s.  pageId=18011. It says true html Id is id_BuCwSep.

Comment: This webpage is a system page template

Comment: How can I hide it on specific forums only using the pageId. There are forums for teachers who are allowed to see each other’s profile. Sorry I tried search for css codes online but it only remove  the hyperlink and image together. We want to  keep the image and make the hyperlink a regular text

Comment: I am not a programmer of any kind so it is what I

Comment: .disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
<a href="#" class="disabled">link</a>

Comment: I want to keep the avatar but prevent users from click on the avatar or the user name below it that will navigate to the user profile